# "natural and artificially flavored" or "naturally and artificially flavored"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, coordinating-conjunctions

I saw a food label that read:

"**natural and artificially flavored**"

A friend suggested this was the correct wording:

"**naturally and artificially flavored**"

Which is correct and why?

Comment: Either could be correct depending on what is meant. I think natural and artificial flavors might have actual regulatory criteria, whereas "natural" is just a feel-good phrase. So I suppose something could be "natural" with artificial flavoring while still meeting FDA guidelines (assuming you're in the US). However, I'm going to flip all the cards and assume the label means it contains both natural and artificial flavors, in which case your second alternative would be correct.

Answer (score 4):

The second clause:

> Naturally and artificially flavored

means the food is flavored both naturally and artificially. This is because the word "naturally" is an ***adverb*** (because of the "-ly") at the end (*caution: see comments*). Adverbs modify verbs and adjectives. In this case, ***naturally*** modifies the *adjective* ***flavored***.

However, the logic of this clause escapes me. How can something be *flavored* **naturally**? Perhaps there is some natural flavoring process of which I am unaware but it seems oxymoronic. (*This is now answered in comments.*)

The clause:

> Natural and artificially flavored

means the food is *natural* **and** it is also *flavored artificially*. The word *natural* functions as an adjective and thus modifies a noun (i.e., the food).

Comment: It would be sil**ly**, if not a fol**ly** to app**ly** your suffix rule to identify adverbs.  If you'd care to bet on it, you might find it cost**ly**, but probably not dead**ly**.  I await your rep**ly**.  (*Naturally* is an adverb because of what it modifies, not because of its suffix.)

Comment: @deadrat: Point taken. Well played, sir. Well played. +1! However, how would you rephrase my description of the general pattern (imperfect as it may be) that many adverbs end with "-ly"? Which is different than every word that ends in "-ly" is an adverb? What is the "helpful hint" you would advise?

Comment: I should have asked your forgiveness in advance for being a wiseass.  Your forbearance becomes you.  I'd say that *naturally* follows a common process in English for forming adverbs by adding the suffix *-ly* to adjectives.

Comment: To answer your logic conundrum, in the US something is naturally flavored (per federal regulation) if it has ingredients that are natural flavors, those agents that are extracted from food.  So naturally-flavored cherry water would have cherry extracts added.  Artificially-flavored cherry water would have synthesized benzaldehyde added.  In any case, your answer merits an upvote.

Comment: Upvote from me as well. I don't think it's likely that anyone would ever refer to a product being both naturally *and* artificially flavoured, as one kind of precludes the other. (in other words, as soon as you add artificial flavouring it's no longer naturally flavoured)